# Lubuntu 17.10 Panel Digital Clock/Calendar Error

Tags: lubuntu, evolution, calendar

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I'm fairly new to Linux and have an error within my digital clock/calender app within the panel I cannot figure out how to fix. I'm running Lubuntu 17.10 x32 ((kernel: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic (i686)) on a 2007 Macbook (white). I've been able to change the time set-up to 12 hr. am/pm without any issues, however when you left-click on the digital clock to display it's interal calendar there is a error set of sequencial numbers in the 1st column of the calendar's matrix starting at a random point (this month it starts with #5). After this weird error column, the calendar matrix is correct (starting with Sunday and it's date displayed correctly). Does anyone know how to delete this 1st error column with the random vertical numbers couting up? Can this issue be easily fixed by putting in a command code within the Digital Clock Settings (i.e. like with the time set-up)?

Thanks for any/all help concerning my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are not anything random at all they are the week number of the year. February starts on the 5th week of the year so that is why it is number 5. I do not think you can remove those with any ease. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/CustomizingTheClock

however this does not have anything on setting up the calendar to not show weeks.